# How to remove decile marks in partial dependence plots of sklearn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

In this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_partial_dependence.html) on how to create partial dependence plots, it is explained that the ticks on the x-axis are decile marks. However, the API does not tell how to active/deactivate them. I tried finding a way of removing those, but so far no success has been achieved.

I'd appreciate any help in removing the bottom ticks. Thank you!

[image: Partial dependence plots]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines are attributes of the [`PartialDependenceDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.PartialDependenceDisplay.html#sklearn.inspection.PartialDependenceDisplay%5D) returned by [`plot_partial_dependence`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.plot_partial_dependence.html#sklearn.inspection.plot_partial_dependence). The attributes are called `deciles_vlines_` (for vertical lines) and `deciles_hlines_` for horizontal lines. If you don't want to show them you can set them to not be visible with e.g. [`plt.setp`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html#matplotlib-pyplot-setp)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
disp = plot_partial_dependence(...)
plt.setp(disp.deciles_vlines_, visible=False)
```